# One database per COSMOS instance or multiple databases in single COSMOS instance?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are new to COSMOS and migrating our multiple applications to cloud. What would be the pros & cons if we have one database per COSMOS instance or all applications databases in single COSMOS instance, will that be cost effective? Because if Microsoft bill on usage RU/s and storage, and not on how many instances of COSMOS are running, what difference it will make to have single database in each COSMOS instance?

Example-
Approach A :
COSMOS Resource1 > Database1 > Container1
COSMOS Resource1 > Database2 > Container2
Approach B:
COSMOS Resource1 > Database1 > Container1
COSMOS Resource2 > Database2 > Container2

Which approach is better?

Comment: What did you end up doing and what were the considerations? I'm also trying to find what a good practice is for this kind of a scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Pros**

- The database can have multiple containers. Each container can have it's own RU quota or you can have them share RU's by placing the quota on the database level. This could save you money by sharing RU's across your whole suite of container needs without the hassle of managing each containers cost.
- You get the ease of connection information as your endpoint and key are the same for all of your containers as they are in one database.
- Adding more RU's benefits all containers not just one.

**Cons**

- If you have a really read/write intensive application that takes up a lot of RU's, combining containers under one provision quota could leave your other applications receiving errors as there are no RU's left for them to perform their operations.
- Someone obtains your key and endpoint, all of your containers are exposed since they are on under the same database. This can expose your companies full data inventory to a hacker.
- You can't control cost to a fine point. Meaning if you have a container that doesn't need much RU's, this container could have a 400 RU provision and only cost you $20 or dollars, while you place the bulk of your budget toward the RU hungry app. Separation allows you pin point control over RU distibution/cost.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput

**Additional tid bits.**
Change feed allows you to connect a function, etc. to events within cosmos and it would allow you to sync data to an outside database like SQL Server, ElasticSearch, and/or Redis. I've seen a lot of people/companies use that serverless power to sync ElasticSearch with very little code.

Make sure you choose your partition key carefully and never do a operation without it. Sometimes the difference can be over 100 RU's on a query.

Comment: Though partition key choice is important, keep in mind that you can migrate data to a new container with a different partitioning strategy later if it turns out not to work so well. Though that isn't trivial, it's still very much doable.

Comment: not sure what you mean by your last point. nobody prevents you from creating an additional database with a single container with 400 ru.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your answer. My question is not around one database single container/ one database multiple containers. What I am trying to understand is is it a good practice to create multiple COSMOS resources and then add required database and containers in it? I have updated my question with approaches